# How to use info in a dataframe and apply it to another dataframe? (Counties are urban/rural)?

Tags: r

I am new to Stackflow so I apologize in advance if my question isn't completely clear.

I am using R.

So I have 2 data frames.. one is Census Bureau data containing all counties in the United States and if they are classified as rural or urban. In my other dataframe, I have iNaturalist occurrence data of a moth species and I have counties and states for those occurrences.

I want to mutate a new column in the iNaturalist dataframe classifying each county and state as urban or rural using the Census Bureau data. However, I don't know how to narrow down the county data or link it to urban/rural like it is in the Census Bureau data. I'm just not sure how to achieve it through code. I've included code for heads of both dataframes. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
head_of_iNat_data <- structure(list(id = c(1031950L, 2377237L, 2377432L, 4284321L, 
4343263L, 4378730L), observed_on = c("2014-10-23", "2015-11-13", 
"2015-11-13", "2016-10-06", "2016-10-13", "2016-10-10"), Year = c("2014", 
"2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2016"), Month = c("10", "11", 
"11", "10", "10", "10"), Day = c("23", "13", "13", "06", "13", 
"10"), quality_grade = c("research", "research", "research", 
"research", "research", "research"), url = c("http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/1031950", 
"http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/2377237", "http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/2377432", 
"http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/4284321", "http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/4343263", 
"http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/4378730"), captive_cultivated = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), latitude = c(32.586924, 32.58703748, 
32.586952, 30.27109297, 33.15875283, 33.17152287), longitude = c(-97.102204, 
-97.102051, -97.101858, -97.72142226, -97.0424805, -97.15339088
), coordinates_obscured = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE), scientific_name = c("Amorpha juglandis", "Amorpha juglandis", 
"Amorpha juglandis", "Amorpha juglandis", "Amorpha juglandis", 
"Amorpha juglandis"), taxon_id = c(84023L, 84023L, 84023L, 84023L, 
84023L, 84023L), state = c("texas", "texas", "texas", "texas", 
"texas", "texas"), county = c("tarrant", "tarrant", "tarrant", 
"travis", "denton", "denton")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
head_of_census_bureau <- structure(list(i_2015_geoid = c(1001L, 1003L, 1005L, 1007L, 1009L, 
1011L), x2010_census_total_population = c("54,571", "182,265", 
"27,457", "22,915", "57,322", "10,914"), county = c("Autauga County", 
"Baldwin County", "Barbour County", "Bibb County", "Blount County", 
"Bullock County"), state = c(" Alabama", " Alabama", " Alabama", 
" Alabama", " Alabama", " Alabama"), x2010_census_urban_population = c("31,650", 
"105,205", "8,844", "7,252", "5,760", "5,307"), x2010_census_rural_population = c("22,921", 
"77,060", "18,613", "15,663", "51,562", "5,607"), x2010_census_percent_rural = c(42, 
42.3, 67.8, 68.4, 90, 51.4), classification = c("mostly urban", 
"completely rural", "completely rural", "completely rural", "mostly rural", 
"completely rural")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do the Census Bureau Data and the iNaturalist data have the same counties?

Comment: @the_one_neuron Hi, yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. The Census Bureau has urban/rural classifications for all counties in each U.S. state. The iNaturalist data only has select counties in certain states. So I have all the info I need. I'm just not sure how to achieve it through code.

Comment: can you use `dput` so we can see a sample of each set of data

Comment: @the_one_neuron Yes, I edited the post with the code! Ideally, want to mutate a new column in the iNat data listing urban/rural for each county using the info from the Census data

Comment: None of your counties actually coincide between datasets, but this sounds like `merge(iNat, subset(census, select = c(state, county, classification)), by = c("state", "county"), all.x = TRUE)` or `dplyr::left_join`. Also, `census$state` appears to use Title Case whereas `iNat$state` is lower case. Those need to be normalized somehow (or you can use `fuzzyjoin` and its stringdist joins).

Comment: @r2evans Thank you, I made counties uppercase in both dataframes and I removed "county" in the census bureau county column. I used `merge(iNat, subset(census, select = c(state, county, classification)), by = c("state", "county"), all.x = TRUE)` however, the classification column in the new dataframe contains all NAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merges and `dplyr::*_join` verbs require *equality*, and your data lacks that for several reasons.

- `"Blount county" !=` "Blount"`
- `"Blount" != "blount"` (case)
- `" alabama" != "alabama"` (blank-spaces)

It is perfectly reasonable to modify the `state` and `county` values in-place. However, I find it often useful to *not* replace them, but to add fields, so that (if needed) I have the original values untouched. So for now, new columns.

```r
census$state_lc <- trimws(tolower(census$state))
census$county_lc <- trimws(gsub(" county", "", tolower(census$county)))
iNat$state_lc <- trimws(tolower(iNat$state))
iNat$county_lc <- trimws(tolower(iNat$county))
```

The above might be sufficient for your real data, but it does nothing with the data that you have supplied. (Please, when providing sample data, at least make sure you have the same state and county in both frames.) To fix this, I will arbitrarily change one row from `census` to match a county in `iNat`.

```r
census$state_lc[1] <- iNat$state_lc[1]
census$county_lc[1] <- iNat$county_lc[1]
```

From here, run the `merge`.

```r
merge(iNat, subset(census, select = c(state_lc, county_lc, classification)), by = c("state_lc", "county_lc"), all.x = TRUE)
#   state_lc county_lc      id observed_on Year Month Day quality_grade                                             url captive_cultivated latitude longitude coordinates_obscured   scientific_name taxon_id state  county classification
# 1    texas    denton 4343263  2016-10-13 2016    10  13      research http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/4343263              FALSE 33.15875 -97.04248                FALSE Amorpha juglandis    84023 texas  denton           <NA>
# 2    texas    denton 4378730  2016-10-10 2016    10  10      research http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/4378730              FALSE 33.17152 -97.15339                 TRUE Amorpha juglandis    84023 texas  denton           <NA>
# 3    texas   tarrant 1031950  2014-10-23 2014    10  23      research http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/1031950              FALSE 32.58692 -97.10220                FALSE Amorpha juglandis    84023 texas tarrant   mostly urban
# 4    texas   tarrant 2377237  2015-11-13 2015    11  13      research http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/2377237              FALSE 32.58704 -97.10205                FALSE Amorpha juglandis    84023 texas tarrant   mostly urban
# 5    texas   tarrant 2377432  2015-11-13 2015    11  13      research http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/2377432              FALSE 32.58695 -97.10186                FALSE Amorpha juglandis    84023 texas tarrant   mostly urban
# 6    texas    travis 4284321  2016-10-06 2016    10  06      research http://www.inaturalist.org/observations/4284321              FALSE 30.27109 -97.72142                FALSE Amorpha juglandis    84023 texas  travis           <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this won't work here is what I tried to solve your problem. The problem is that there are likely duplicated county names in different states. I tried to solve that problem but it is hard to tell if what I did will work without having access to the full datasets. There is also a high likelihood that county names are structured differently between the two data sets, for example, st clair could be written as st. clair or saint clair in the census bureau dataset. If the datasets are publically available I would be happy to take a look

```
completely.rural <- head_of_census_bureau %>%
  filter(classification == "completely rural")

mostly.urban <- head_of_census_bureau %>% 
  filter(classification == "mostly urban")

mostly.rural <- head_of_census_bureau %>%
  filter(classification == "mostly rural")

head_of_iNat_data$county <- gsub("(^[[:alpha:]])", "\\U\\1", head_of_iNat_data$county, perl=TRUE)
head_of_iNat_data$state <- gsub("(^[[:alpha:]])", "\\U\\1", head_of_iNat_data$state, perl=TRUE)

head_of_iNat_data$county <- paste(head_of_iNat_data$county, "County")

inaturalist.completely.rural <- head_of_iNat_data %>%
  filter(county %in% completely.rural$county) %>%
  filter(state %in% completely.rural$state)

inaturalist.completely.rural$classification <- "completely rural"

inaturalist.mostly.urban <- head_of_iNat_data %>%
  filter(county %in% mostly.urban$county) %>%
  filter(state %in% mostly.urban$state)

inaturalist.mostly.urban$classification <- "mostly.urban"


inaturalist.mostly.rural <- head_of_iNat_data %>%
  filter(county %in% mostly.rural$county) %>%
  filter(state %in% mostly.rural$state)

inaturalist.mostly.rural$classification <- "mostly rural"

iNaturalist <- rbind(inaturalist.completely.rural,inaturalist.mostly.urban,inaturalist.mostly.rural)

#this will show you the counties with names that were spelled incorrectly
no.classification <- head_of_iNat_data %>%
  filter(!county %in% iNaturalist$county) %>%
  filter(state %in% iNaturalist$state)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried `inaturalist.completely.rural <- head_of_iNat_data %>%
  filter(county %in% completely.rural$county) %>%
  filter(state %in% completely.rural$state)` and it yielded an empty dataframe. I've made the counties uppercase in both dataframes and have cleaned up the county column in the census bureau dataframe. I've tried using left_join but I'm getting NAs in all the columns of the census bureau. Not sure what I'm missing? `joining_the_two <- left_join(iNat_data, census_bureau, by = "county")

Comment: Both dataframes are publically available. How can I share them with you?

Comment: (Saying data is publicly available is nice, but ... *where*?)